# multer "req.file" is undefined for http request from script but working with html form tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I've built a simple file uploader using multer on Node.js. It is working fine when I upload the file with html form tag like this :

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="userFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

But if I try to do the same from the javaScript using Angular JS $http request , it throws an error saying "req.file is undefined". It throws the same error on uploading using postman.

**My angular $http request :**

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/file', formData, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    })
    .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**My Upload api :**

```
app.post('/api/file', function(req, res) {
var upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
}).single('userFile')
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log(req);
    if(req.file) {
        var buffer = req.file.buffer;
        var filename = req.file.originalname;
        fs.writeFile('./uploads/' + filename, buffer, 'binary', function(err) {
            if (err) throw err
            res.end('File is uploaded')
        })
    } else {
        res.end('Invalid request : file not found')
    }
});
})
```

There are many similar questions about this but none of them helped me solve this. 
Can anyone let me know the issue here please ? Thanks.

Comment: change `userFile` to file and how are you getting file object in angular.?

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma . Changing userFile to file worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have added the answer so others can refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `userFile` to `file`

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
}).single('file')
```